# Must there be notification alerts for anything to appear on lock screen?

Tags: ios, notifications, screen-lock, iphone

I disabled Instagram from posting a notification alert ( banner or alert ). 
However any posted item or notification do not show in the lock screen or notification center.

Prior to ios7 this causes no problem, as comments/notifications from such an app show up in the lock screen or notification center, but is this feature disabled now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Yes, I need to have some sort of alert (banner or alert window) for anything to show on the lock screen. Kind of sucks since iOS 5 didn't need such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

How did you disable the notification alerts?

You should have three different settings in the notification settings:

- Alert Style: if you set this to none, you will not see any banners or alerts when you have your phone unlocked.
- Show in Notification Center: you should keep this on
- Show on Lock Screen: and this one on

Those settings should be independent to each other I believe.

Comment: I chose the first option, as in "None", hence disabling notification alerts .....